# Buttons or list in Whatsapp-Web.js

Tags: node.js, message, whatsapp, whatsapi

I'm trying to build an app in node.js and my objective is to send WhatsApp messages to my list of clients, and for that purpose I'm using WhatsApp-Web.js.

I included media message and text as a caption, but I want to add buttons or list in the messages which is not sending.

I read the whole guide, gone through their whole documentation but it still not working. It's not causing any error but the buttons are not sending to the users.

Can anyone solve my problem or suggest to use other library? Because I need to add the buttons.

Or should I switch to any other language?

Answer (score 0):

Buttons are deprecated in the libraries like whatsapp-web.js and baileys as per today. You need to use the official WhatsApp api if you want to use them before these lib owner patch them.

Some more information by the owner of whatsapp-web.js was given [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hv1R1rLeVVE&pp=ygUVYnV0dG9uIHdoYXRzYXBwd2ViIGpz) you can read it.